# Use date drop down and have column validation

Tags: excel, validation

I am using data validation on a series of cells that allow the user to select from a set of dates. The dates are based in another sheet and are basically listed as Today(), Today()-1, Today()-2 etc. all the way to -28. This keeps the drop down selection current\dynamic.
What I wish to do though is make each date in the cell be greater than the previous cells date but I only know how to do this using the column validation and I'm obviously already using this to produce the dynamic date list.
Any ideas?
Thanks
[Sample image of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sat84.png)

Comment: please show the sample excel.

Comment: Karpak - is the screenshot enough?

Comment: yes, it should be enough

Comment: Great...I added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using data validation. However you can do this using VBA. Press Alt+F11 to activate VBA editor and double click on the sheet where you want to put this validation and enter the following script there. and save your excel then you will have your validation in place.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim OldValue As String
Dim NewValue As String
Dim PrevCell As String
Dim CurRow As Integer
Dim CurCol As Integer

On Error GoTo Exitsub
CurRow = Target.Row
CurCol = Target.Column

If CurRow = 1 Or CurCol = 1 Then GoTo Exitsub    ' if current row not equal to row 1 or current column = 1, no need to validate

Application.EnableEvents = False

NewValue = Target.Value
Application.Undo
OldValue = Target.Value
Target.Value = NewValue
PrevCell = Cells(CurRow, CurCol - 1).Value

If Trim(NewValue) = "" Then GoTo Exitsub

If (PrevCell > NewValue) Then
    MsgBox "Date is less than previous cell", vbCritical, "Error"
    Target.Value = OldValue
    GoTo Exitsub
End If
Exitsub:
Target.NumberFormat = "DD/MMM;@"
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

you may need to change the row number and column in the following statement according to your requirement

```
If CurRow = 1 Or CurCol = 1 Then GoTo Exitsub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I cannot get it to work though. Is there a way to attach the workbook so you can take a look? Is it a problem that I am using dates and not integer's?

Comment: You can attach the work sheet as part of your question.

Comment: I can't see any attachment options. Do you need a certain level of reputation before you can attach?

Comment: You copy and paste the formula again and let me know, what problem you are facing if you include this. I changed one = sign, and It should work now.

Comment: That's working now just a couple of problems. 1. The date format I set is DD/MMM however it is reverting to US and not UK date format. I have changed the format in both worksheets to UK DD/MMM however the issue is still present, the 7th of Nov is showing as the 11th of Jul . 2. Colum A must be excluded from the validation. Thanks

Comment: You try with Target.NumberFormat = "DD/MMM;@" just above the End Sub. I edited the program as well.

Comment: is this working fine? If it works, please accept this as a right answer, so that it will be useful for other users.